# CURL DOMXPath different values

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping, domxpath

I have this curl function that extracts the html from a website.

```
function curl($url){
    $headers[]  = "User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13";
    $headers[]  = "Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
    $headers[]  = "Accept-Language:en-us,en;q=0.5";
    $headers[]  = "Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate";
    $headers[]  = "Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
    $headers[]  = "Keep-Alive:115";
    $headers[]  = "Connection:keep-alive";
    $headers[]  = "Cache-Control:max-age=0";

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    $data = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $data;
}
```

And in order to retrieve the data I use :

```
$html = curl($USE_URL);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$data = new DOMXPath($doc);




$date_list= $data->query('............');
$name_list= $data->query('............');

echo $date_list->length;
echo $name_list->length;
```

If I run this code in the '**localhost**' it works smoothly (giving me length **52,52**): . but if I use the exactly same code on my altervista website it gives me that the `date_list` length is zero! (length **0,52**)

The ***date_list*** format that I extract is a string like "08-09-2018 12:47"

Is there something wrong the the curl $headers maybe?

Comment: Make sure that's  Curl is installed in  your website's server

Comment: Yep is installed. It actually works. I can extract everything exept  the date_list

Answer (score 0):

Weirdly I solved this by changing the query: I had to work my way around it: so basically my new query extracts a larget set of data (eg "abcd deddeh dede 12:30 dhhh") and manually extract my real data by manipulating the string (using split methods..)

```
$date_list= $data->query('.....HERE......');
```

I think that when CURL downloads the page it doesn't let it completely unvaried.